# Consumer surplus for demand curve at the given sales level $x$

Tags: calculus

[image]

The square root is throwing me of doing the integration. Can someone please show the steps of integration.

Answer is $\$26.19$

[image]

Ok then can someone show me how we got the integration here?

Comment: Having your title in all caps is wildly inappropriate. Like everywhere else on the web, it is construed as yelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the curve at $x = 50$ is $\sqrt{16 - 0.14\times50}=\sqrt{9}=3$.  Thus, the consumer surplus will be given by
$$
\int_0^{50}(p(x)-50)dx = \int_0^{50}\left[\sqrt{16 - 0.14x}-3\right]dx
$$
As Tyler indicated, find this integral using the $u$-substitution of $u = 16 - 0.14 x$.

---

So, we want the function whose derivative is $\sqrt{16 - 0.14x}$. If we naively just integrated the outside function, we would get $\frac{2}{3} (16 - 0.14x)^{3/2}$.  Let's check what the derivative of this function would be.  We find, using the chain rule,
$$
\frac d{dx} \frac{2}{3}(16 - 0.14x)^{3/2} = 
\sqrt{16 - 0.14 x} \cdot(-0.14)
$$
This is almost what we want, except that we have a $-0.14$ multiplying at the end.  So, we're going to take what we got originally and divide by $-0.14$.  We then have
$$
\frac d{dx} \frac{1}{-0.14}\frac{2}{3}(16 - 0.14x)^{3/2} = 
\frac{1}{-0.14}\sqrt{16 - 0.14 x} \cdot(-0.14)
= \sqrt{16 - 0.14 x}
$$
And that's the derivative we wanted!  So, we now know that
$$
\int \sqrt{16 - 0.14 x} = -\frac{1}{0.14}\frac{2}{3}(16 - 0.14x)^{3/2} + C
$$
Use this to find the integral you need.

Comment: is there another way to do it without the u substitution @Omnomnomnom

Comment: The $u$-substitution is just a fancy name for the chain rule applied to integrals. What else do you want?

Comment: If you don't like $u$-substitution, you could try to find the function whose derivative is $\sqrt{16 - 0.14x}-3$ in some other way; basically by guess and check.  Is there any particular reason you don't want to use $u$-substitution?

Comment: I have not learned the chain rule in integration.

Comment: Well since this is an economics question, maybe your economics teacher supposes you know it. There isn't really another way to do the problem. Sorry. If all you need is an approximate answer, try using numerical integration like the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

Comment: I've added a little something.  That should help you get through the simpler reverse-chain-rule problems, but things won't always work out that way.  Hopefully, you'll have some knowledge of the chain rule before you're expected to compute the more difficult integrals.

Comment: That is, knowledge of $u$-substitution (the "reverse-chain-rule").

Answer (score 1):

$\int \sqrt{16-0.14x} \,\mathrm{d}x =\int (16-0.14x)^{1/2} \,\mathrm{d}x$

Let $u = 16 - 0.14x$, $\mathrm{d}u = -0.14 \mathrm{d}x$. Evaluate.